# Python Opencv drawContour error

Tags: python, opencv

It work, but my contour's color is black. How to change it to red or green?

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    img = cv2.imread('1.jpg',0)
    img1 = cv2.imread('5.jpg',0)
    dest = cv2.subtract(img, img1)
    res = cv2.bitwise_not(dest)
    ret , threshold = cv2.threshold(res,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)          
    cv2.namedWindow('thresimage', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('thresimage',threshold)
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print "Number of contours detected %d -> "%len(contours)
    cv2.drawContours(threshold,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
    cv2.namedWindow('contour', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('contour',threshold)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjm6d.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
```

**Second**

```
ret , threshold = cv2.threshold(res,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
# ...
cv2.drawContours(threshold,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
```

You draw in color `(0,255,0)` on binary `threshed` image, then it will always be the first element `0`, that's black. You should convert gray to BGR first, then draw color.

```
canvas = cv2.cvtColor(threshold, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.drawContours(canvas,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It work, but i can't see the contours after draw it.

Comment: @BùiChíThanh Post your result, otherwise, we cannot diagnose it.