# How to draw contours using opencv in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have following image preprocessed:

[image]

Now I want to use `findContours` method in order to find cells from image and then use `drawContours` in order draw contour for every cell from image. I do this but nothing is shown.

```
contours =  cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

I receive the following error.

> contours is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

**Another answers didn't helped me.**

I also use following solution.

```
contours =  cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
ctr = numpy.array(contours).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(numpy.int32)
cv2.drawContours(img, ctr, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

But this solution didn't draw anything on the given image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**, OpenCV 4.0 change the `cv2.findContours`. So I modify the code example. And a more general way:

```
cnts, hiers  = cv2.findContours(...)[:-2]
```

---

`cv2.findContours` returns a tuple, not just the contours. You can do like this:

```
## Find contours
if cv2.__version__.startswith("3."):
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(bimg.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
else:
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(bimg, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

## Draw contours 
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

---

Related similar questions:

(1) [Python Opencv drawContour error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855046/python-opencv-drawcontour-error/47855156#47855156)

(2) [How to use `cv2.findContours` in different OpenCV versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291581/opencv-with-python-video-edge-detection-typeerror/48292371#48292371)

Comment: Thank you ! It seems that I used version > 3.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Notice, OpenCV 4.0 change the `cv2.findContours` back, so I modify the code example.

Answer (score 1):

The tuple returned by `cv2.findContours` has the form `(im, contours, hierarchy)` where `im` is the image with contours visualized, `contours` is a tuple of two numpy arrays in the form `(x_values, y_values)` and `heirarchy` depends on the retrieval mode. Since you are using CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, `heirarchy` doesn't have much significance.